# A one line function to convert a hh:mm:ss.zzz time QString to milliseconds?

Tags: c++, qt, milliseconds, time-format

I'm using Qt and I have a time `QString` of format `hh:mm:ss:zzz`, such as `01:59:25.345`. I am wondering if there is already some handy functions in Qt or c++ that can easily convert this to milliseconds. As to the `QTime::fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay(12334).toString("hh:mm:ss.zzz");` for the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* your format of `Qt::ISODateWithMs` is considered valid ISO 8601.  Just prepend an aribitrary date with a `T` delimiter between date a and time.

```
QString timestamp = "2020-01-01T01:59:25.345";
int milliseconds = QDateTime::fromString(timestamp, Qt::ISODateWithMs).time().msecsSinceStartOfDay();
```

Also, if the current day is a daylight savings start/end day, I'm not sure how that impacts the calculation, of it it even matters.

Comment: Hi, the first line is invalid. I did try my own QString but it returns 0

Comment: The function returns 0

Comment: Oh I figured it. I appended a dummy date in front of timestamp and it worked. `QString dummyDate = QString("2020-01-01T")` , `int milliseconds = QDateTime::fromString(dummyDate+timestamp, Qt::ISODateWithMs).time().msecsSinceStartOfDay();`

Comment: Yep, I had just arrived at the same conclusion a minute after you did.